# 2 time traveling young men

Tags: story-identification, prehistoric

I read this book ages ago, probably in the 60s:

Two young men go back in time to prehistoric times. I can't remember how they got there, but they meet up with a young man from a tribe of people and live with them. There are some politics going on, with a not-so-altruistic leader who is trying to take over. I only remember that this bad guy was killed when a volcano erupted and he was hit by a flaming, flying boulder.

I know it's not a lot to go on, but I do remember that the boy from the tribe said the leader would become rich if there was a war and the modern boys said this was still true in our times.

Comment: I don't remember the volcano bit, but other than that, this could be [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe) or possibly [Life, the Universe and Everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life,_the_Universe_and_Everything).

Comment: @bitmask Doesn't seem to match this much, and timeframe is wrong.

Comment: This recalls something by Andre Norton I read a long time ago.